# How to redirect a user to the current page when logging in or out?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I cant seem to get this to work. What I'm trying to do is setup a "Login" link so that when the user clicks on it and logs in, it takes them back to the page they were on when they originally clicked the login button. I'd also like to do the same for when they press logout. Essentially I'm also stopping them seeing the dashboard at all.

Here's the code I have...

```
<a href="http://www.anymenu.co.uk/aberdeen/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php the_permalink();       ?>">Login</a>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin](http://www.theblog.ca/wplogin-redirect) should do what you need.

Try this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
```

Comment: i need the redirect to go to their current page though, which I dont believe that plugin can do...